# Button is not a square but width and height are the same in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Im new to Android programming. I am trying to create a simple Tic Tac Toe but I am struggling with the button sizes right now. My buttons have the same height and length but they are more wide than high. Can someone give me a hint?

Here is the code from the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:background="#2190F3"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="@string/title" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either, Set `layout_width` of your `LinearLayout` containing button to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`. Check below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:background="#2190F3"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="title" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Or** remove `layout_weight="1"` from your button. Check below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:background="#2190F3"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="title" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! But why? Could you please explain?

Comment: According your requirements you can't use both `match_parent ` with `android:layout_weight="1"`. When you use `layout_weight` to 1, that means you have cover all the width of its parent. You can check the difference by removing `android:layout_weight="1"` from one of your button in your initial layout